# Designing an intelligent creature that originates from Europa

Tags: creature-design, aliens

I would like this species to have the same intelligence as Humans, Would it be possible for them to communicate using bioluminescence? I want them to be able to have a culture and civilisation. Could my species evolve a very hard exo-skeleton so they can survive on the surface briefly and then retreat back underneath the ice after one Europan day or a little longer?

Comment: You're asking a lot of different questions.

Comment: If you refine this to make it clear what environment they are in, it will be easier to generate a good answer.  It took me a couple of readings to figure out where these critters are.

Comment: Ask one question.  Suggest you focus on the hard shell, start with a straw-man idea, and use the [tag:reality-check] tag.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: Yes.**

Long answer:

**Would it be possible for them to communicate using bio-luminescence?**
Yes. Real world example would be the cuttlefish which communicate by [changing colour of its skin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuttlefish#Communication). Sure, it's not bio-luminescence, but it's still communication based on visual signs. It wouldn't be that farfetched for a cuttlefish to add light to their skin signals if they had the possibility to use bio-luminescence.

**Could my species evolve a very hard exo-skeleton so they can survive on the surface briefly and then retreat back underneath the ice after one Europan day or a little longer?**
Yes. Several creatures on earth have an exoskeleton and Crustaceans have been around for a very long time and several of them live at fairly high pressure at the bottom of Earth's oceans. It might not be entirely comparable to the environment on Europa, but when it comes to evolution, then we know from earth that "where there is a will, there is a way". That is, as long as life starts on a planet, then it will find a way to adapt to whatever the universe tosses at it. Thus, there is nothing (from an evolutionary perspective) which prevents your creatures from developing a sturdy exoskeleton which can handle the European environment, if you want them to.